# Determining matplotlib stylesheet keys

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a standard method for determining valid stylesheet keys for matplotlib? Currently I use a mixture of searching on SO, guesswork and this [example stylesheet](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html?highlight=style%20sheets%20reference) as a reference. Is there a complete list of valid keys for a stylesheets?

For example if I want to set the colour on a scatter graph to black I could use:

```
import matplotlib as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, color='k')
```

However `axes.scatter.color` is not a valid key for a stylesheet. I can set the marker type using the key `scatter.marker`, but `scatter.marker.color` doesn't exist.

Comment: It might be that you are mixing two questions here. I answered the one about getting all valid rc Params. If you try to colorize a plot and it fails, please ask a different question about it but make it especially clear what you expect to happen.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest No you answered the essence of my question which is about how to find valid keys for the stylesheet without the guesswork. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All valid rc Params are part of the [matplotlib rc file](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) shown on the matplotlib page. (If you find a valid rc param that is missing in that file, please report it to the matplotlib GitHub tracker.)

You may also print a list of all rc Params as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for k,v in plt.rcParams.items():
    print(k)
```